# F# method returns null instead of Option

Tags: .net, f#, .net-4.6.1

I develop `F#` application `.net 4.6.1` on `VS2015`. i have methods:

```
type CommonHelper = 
    static member SideEffectOnNull act x = if x = null then act(); x else x
    static member SideEffectOnNotNull act x = if x <> null then act(); x else x
```

...

```
    static member GetPerformanceCounter ( fname: CounterFullName ) = 

        let getCounterInternal ( counterFullName: CounterFullName ) =
            Log.Information("Getting counter: {category}\\{name}\\{instance} ",  counterFullName.Category, counterFullName.Name, counterFullName.Instance)
            let receivedCategory = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault( fun x -> String.Equals( x.CategoryName, counterFullName.Category.Category, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) )
            if receivedCategory = null  then
                Serilog.Log.Warning ( "Category not found: {category}", counterFullName.Category ); null
            else
                let receivedCounters = PerforrmanceCounterProxy.GetPerformanceCountersFromCategoryOrNull counterFullName.Instance receivedCategory
                if receivedCounters = null then 
                    Log.Warning ("Instance not found {name}(instance: {instance}) in category {category}", counterFullName.Name, counterFullName.Instance, counterFullName.Category); null
                else
                    receivedCounters.FirstOrDefault( fun y -> String.Equals( y.CounterName, counterFullName.Name.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) 
                    |> CommonHelper.SideEffectOnNull ( fun unit -> Log.Warning ("Name {name}(instance: {instance}) not found for category {category}", counterFullName.Name, counterFullName.Instance, counterFullName.Category) )

        getCounterInternal fname
        |> CommonHelper.SideEffectOnNull (fun unit ->Log.Warning( "Getting counter failed: {category}\\{name}\\{instance}", fname.Category, fname.Name, fname.Instance )) 
        |> CommonHelper.SideEffectOnNotNull (fun unit ->Log.Information( "Getting Counter secceed: {category}\\{name}\\{instance}", fname.Category, fname.Name, fname.Instance ))
        |> (fun x -> if x = null then None else Option.Some(x))
```

But when i call this method i receive `null` instead of `option`.
[image]
 What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess - the problem related to `visual studio 2015`. Because business logic works good, i think `VS2015` UI shows incorrect info

Comment: I've had the default value for that type appear when stepping through - `default(T)` in case of value types and `null` for reference types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In F# it is possible to represent one data-less value of a DU with the `null` constant at runtime. You can instruct the compiler to do so with `CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue`:

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)>]
type A = B | C of int

printfn "%A" (obj.ReferenceEquals( B, null ))  // will print "true"
```

In the above code, the DU value `B` gets compiled to `null`. This is sometimes nice for optimization purposes: instead of allocating an instance every time, I use a constant. Helps if the value is used a lot.

So the `Option` type uses this same technique for the `None` case, and that's why `None` shows up as `null` in the debugger.

One day, the debugger will have appropriate extension points to implement this and other F# features. Until then, the debugger speaks C#, and you get to do the translation.

Comment: The debugger worked fine before VS2015, what happened?

Comment: Are you saying that before 2015 the debugger showed you `None` instead of `null`? Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: Just checked and you're right. I must have been mentally substituting `Nones` for `nulls`.

Comment: Issue is reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44030/f-debugging-option-types-returns-null.html and https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3716