# Why are some properties (e.g. IsSome and IsNone) for FSharpOption not visible from C#?

Tags: c#, properties, f#, interop

It seems to me that some properties of the F# option type are not visible from C# projects. By inspecting the types, I can see more or less the reason, but I don't really understand what exactly is going on, why these choices have been made or how best to circumvent the issue.

Here's some snippets demonstrating the issue. I have a VS2015 solution containing two projects, a C# project and a F# project. In the F# project, I have a class defined as follows:

```
type Foo () =

    member this.Bar () = Some(1)
```

Furthermore, in F# I can write something like this:

```
let option = (new Foo()).Bar()
let result = if option.IsNone then "Is none" else "Is some"
```

So it would appear that the option type has a property named `IsNone`. Now, in the C# project, I have a reference to the .dll compiled from the F# project. This allows me to write e.g.

```
var optionType = new Foo().Bar();
```

The variable `optionType` is an `FSharpOption<int>`. As I noted above, when I use option types in F# projects, I usually have access to for example the `IsSome` and `IsNone` properties. However, when I try to write something like `optionType.IsNone`, I get the CS1546 error "Property, indexer or event ... is not supported by the language". In concordance with this, Intellisense does not detect the property:

[image: Intellisense does not detect the IsSome and IsNone properties]

Now, when inspecting the FSharpOption type, I can see that the IsNone and IsSome "properties" appear as static methods:

[image: FSharpOption class signature from C#]

On the other hand, when I inspect the type from F#, I see the following instead:

[image: FSharpOption class signature from F#]

Here, the "existence" of the properties `IsSome` and `IsNone` is evident. Hovering the cursor over these properties, VS2015 gives me the following note: "The containing type can use 'null' as a representation value for its nullary union case. This member will be compiled as a static member." This is the reason why the properties aren't available except as static methods (as noted by lukegv and Fyodor Soikin).

So, the situation appears to be the following: The compiled FSharpOption type does not have any IsNone and IsSome properties. Something is going on behind the scenes in F# to enable functionality emulating these properties.

I know that I can get around this by using the `OptionModule` in Microsoft.FSharp.Core. However, it seems that this functionality is a conscious choice by the architects of the F# core library. What are the reasons for the choice? And is using `OptionModule` the right solution, or is there a better way to use the `FSharpOption<T>` type from C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has to do with how `option` is compiled. The `Some` values get compiled straightforwardly as creating an instance of the class and wrapping the value in it. But the `None` values are not really values, they're just `null`.

Try this:

```
let a: int option = Some 1
let b: int option = None
let a_isNull = obj.ReferenceEquals( a, null )   // a_isNull = false
let b_isNull = obj.ReferenceEquals( b, null )   // b_isNull = true
```

(this is also the reason that the `None` values [will show up as `null` in the debugger's Watch window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338857/180286))

This is an optimization that saves a lot of cycles at runtime. (and you can use it for your own union types, too, by applying `CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue`)

Now, since some values of this type may be `null`, you can't really use properties or methods on these values. If the value happens to be `null`, you'll just crash. That's why you should always use the `OptionModule` for all operations.

As for why these properties don't show up in intellisense - that's because they're `static`. Though I'm not sure why they're present there at all. Perhaps a compiler artifact.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that the None values are really null is a good explanation of why the IsNone and IsSome properties are removed. I've edited the question a bit to include yours and lukegv's remark that in the compiled class, the "properties" are static.

Comment: Sooo... Are you still not getting the mechanics and reasons? Anything else is unclear?

Comment: Ah. I was a bit confused why you haven't accepted the answer yet, but then you did right after I wrote the comment.

Comment: There a static `IsSome` method, yes, but there is also a property on the instance, [see source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/499526a5e37fc15ff5a6a9abcd63996037e3c8f1/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3443). It is usable in F# and visible in Intellisense. Why not on the C# side? Yes, you can argue that they would cause trouble on the `null`/`None`, but what is the mechanism that removes them for the "outside world"?

Comment: That property is only a property in F# sense, but not in CLR sense. In the underlying IL, there is no property.

Comment: Ah, got it now. By default, if you use null to represent some values, instance methods don't get compiled as such. You must turn it on explicity via `CompilationRepresentationFlags.Instance`, as is done for `Value` [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/499526a5e37fc15ff5a6a9abcd63996037e3c8f1/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3433)

Answer (score 3):

I am not well versed with F#, but since it is all CLR, my answer is from a C# point of view:

In the generated class definition, both `IsNone` and `IsSome` are static and therefor can't be accessed via the instance `optionType` (neither via IntelliSense, nor in code). The property `Value` is not static and can be accessed.